# Unknown issue in a C++ program using Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, function, class, codeblocks

I'm trying to debug a code. It's really simple but I'm stuck.

Here's what the compiler says:

In function `void initialization()`:

> line 35 error: expected unqualified-id before '-' token

And here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class vars
{
public:

    int coins;
    int coins_sec;

    int gtx750ti;  // The amount of GTX750ti owned by the player
    int gtx760;    // The amount of GTX760 owned by the player
    int gtx770;
    int gtx780;
    int gtxtitan;
    int gtxtitanB;
    int gtxtitanZ;
    int r9270;
    int r9270x;
    int r9280;
    int r9280x;
    int r9290;
    int r9290x;
    int r9295x2;

        int gpuNames[14];       // The names of the different GPUs

    int maxPower;   // The maximum power the PSU can deliver to the components
};

void initialization()
{
        vars.gpuNames[0] = "gtx750ti";
        vars.gpuNames[1] = "gtx760";
        vars.gpuNames[2] = "gtx770";
        vars.gpuNames[3] = "gtx780";
        vars.gpuNames[4] = "gtxtitan";
        vars.gpuNames[5] = "gtxtitanB";
        vars.gpuNames[6] = "gtxtitanZ";
        vars.gpuNames[8] = "r9270";
        vars.gpuNames[9] = "r9270x";
        vars.gpuNames[10] = "r9280";
        vars.gpuNames[11] = "r9280x";
        vars.gpuNames[12] = "r9290";
        vars.gpuNames[13] = "r9290x";
        vars.gpunames[14] = "r9295x2";
}

int main()
{
    vars vars;
    initiation();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vars` is a class. You can't say stuff like `vars.gpuNames[0]`.

Comment: At the scope of `initialization()` `vars` is a _type_ not a _variable_ and the members you are accessing are not `static`. Why do you think this should work?

Comment: To be clear: you've used `vars` as the name of *both* a type *and* a variable--but the type is visible globlally, while the variable is visible only inside of `main`.

Comment: `gpuNames` is also an integer, and you are assigning it with strings, which should give you some compiler error, IF you got post the point of the confusing name of `vars` being a type and a variable at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

As other people's comments have stated, prefer not to have class and variables of the same name, regardless of case.

Also, identifier names are case-sensitive.  Thus "gpuNames" is different than "gpunames".

That said, I suggest you make your name array as static and constant.  This will allow the compiler to create a data table and have the code directly access this table; no assignments will take place.

Example:

```
static const char * gpu_name_table[] =
{
  "gtx750ti";
  "gtx760";
    "gtx770",
    "gtx780",
    "gtxtitan",
    "gtxtitanB",
    "gtxtitanZ",
    "r9270",
    "r9270x",
    "r9280",
    "r9280x",
    "r9290",
    "r9290x",
    "r9295x2",
};
static const unsigned int number_of_gpu_names =
  sizeof(gpu_name_table) / sizeof(gpu_name_table[0]);
```

The above array idiom will allow you to add GPU names without having to change any other variables in your program.  The variable `number_of_gpu_names` is assigned a value by the compiler.